# Merge and Sum totals in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I have a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnDUJ.png) in Excel and I need it to sum the totals of cell B and return the value on the cell after the last value. The following code does that.

```
 Sub Total()

    Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
    "=sum($B$2:" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address & ")"

    End Sub
```

I need it to merge the cells from B to H, format the text to bold and change the color and add the text "Total", [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Z9B.png)

Comment: You have a table, you want to sum the totals of Column B and you have a routine that does this. What is your specific problem? The rest of your post asks for code that does something different, and Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. What have you tried to solve your second problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Total()

    Dim l As Long

    l = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B" & l + 1) = "=sum(B2:B" & l & ")"

    With Range("A" & l + 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    With Range("B" & l + 1 & ":H" & l + 1)
        .MergeCells = True
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    With Range("A" & l + 1 & ":H" & l + 1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Michal Rosa!